# populate listview row from more than one database row

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview and i would like to populate a row with several calculations done on multiple database tables rows winch carry the row id as column (group).

So for example one of my database tables has three rows all of winch have a unique row id for one coloumn and also another column (group) which has the same value for all rows allowing them to be grouped together.

What i would like to do is pass a cursor over each row which has the same value in the column group and do a few things on each row like add,minus,subtract etc. and then add the result from each row to a value which i can then attach to the list view.

How can i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the results in an `Array` and then do your operations you want on each item. Then you use an `arrayAdapter` to put the items in it.

```
public String[][] getResultSetAsArray(Cursor cursor) {

int numberOfColumns = cursor.getColumnCount();
int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

String [][] resultSetAsArray = new String[numberOfColumns][numberOfRows];

for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numberOfColumns; currentColumn++)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < numberOfRows; currentRow++)
    {
    resultSetAsArray[currentColumn][currentRow] = cursor.getString(currentColumn);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
return resultSetAsArray;
}
```

This method gives you all the results of a cursor back in a two-dimensional array. If you only have one column, you just use the method and put `[0]` after it to put it in one array.

Example:

```
String table = tablename;
String[] columns = {column1, column2};
String orderBy = columnNameToOrder;

Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, orderBy); 
String[] column1Values = dbRetrieval.getResultSetAsArray(tabLabelCursor)[0];
String[] column2Values = dbRetrieval.getResultSetAsArray(tabLabelCursor)[1];
String[][] values = dbRetrieval.getResultSetAsArray(tabLabelCursor); // all the database values in a two-dimensional array.
```

Comment: so how do i get the result on each row?? and how do i make an array from that??

Comment: Look at my edit :) I think a List will be a neater solution, but mayby you can start from here.

Comment: Thanks this looks like what i want but I'm not exactly sure where i do the calculations for each row? So for example row one of the database table ads 3 columns together and then finds the result then the same happens for row 2. Then i want the results from both to be added and put into a list view.

Comment: You can get all the columns in one array like the values two-dimensional array above. In another array you can put the results of the operations done on the elements of that array and then use the arrayadapter to put it there.

Comment: Then you should modify the getResultAsArray method. It's perfectly possible